# concatenate strings in .htaccess

Tags: string, .htaccess, concatenation

Seems so simple, proves to be tough to find ...
In my `.htaccess` file I want to create following rewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule (.*)$  %{HTTP_HOST} + /home.html
```

Can someone pls tell me how to concatenate a `.htaccess` variable (HTTP_HOST) and a string (`/home.html`)

And NO, I cannot redirect to `/home.html` directly because this .htaccess file serves 2 different domains which are both each located in a subdirectory in my webspace. Apparently the `.htaccess` file doesn't work when put into a subdirectory .

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a special “concatenation operator” or something – you just place the variable reference into the substitution, it will get parsed in there automatically.

What you should keep in mind though, is that `%{HTTP_HOST}` will contain only the host name, no protocol – so it might be necessary to prefix it with a protocol so that it is not treated as a directory.

```
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/home.html [R]
```

should work. (I added the [R] flag for an explicit redirect [which I guess you want?], because otherwise it might be just an internal one if the host matches the current one.)

Comment: @ CBroe: Spot on! I had tried your concatination solution before, but without the protocoll prefix :(
Now the htaccess does the job! Thnx, Arthur

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to redirect and NOT TO REWRITE the specific domain into `/home.html`? Just simply use a rewrite condition:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} domain1\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /home.html [R]
```

And please explain your question briefly, so I could edit the code to the right one.

Comment: @ Servant: Nope, I really need a rewriteRule because of the configuration of the double domain (see initial question)

Comment: This is possible, `RewriteRule (.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/home.html` and now what do you want?